# Check if variable is a number or array

Tags: php, arrays, numbers

I want to check if the content of a variable is an number or array. `is_array()`, `is_int()`, `is_numeric()` don't really work. Currently I'm using myArray[1] which seems to work. But I'm wondering why one of this function cannot do this for me?

**Edit:**

It seems that I had something like `myArray['id']` as content and this always is an array.

Comment: ...a number 13 is an array? You mean `is_array( 13 ) === true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = is_array(13) ? "yes" : "no";
$int = is_int(13) ? "yes" : "no";
$numeric = is_numeric(13) ? "yes" : "no";

echo $array."\n", $int."\n", $numeric."\n";
```

Replies with

```
no
yes
yes
```

As expected, so I'm not really sure what the issue is here!

It's perhaps worth noting that if you run:

```
$array = is_array("13") ? "yes" : "no";
$int = is_int("13") ? "yes" : "no";
$numeric = is_numeric("13") ? "yes" : "no";

echo $array."\n", $int."\n", $numeric."\n";
```

The response is:

```
no
no
yes
```

Which again is as you'd expect - a string and a number aren't represented as arrays.

Running gettype like this:

```
echo gettype(13);
```

shows it is an `integer`.

Answer (score 2):

this is not a real question.
`is_array()` obviously returns false for the number `13`

Got any *real* problem?

Though PHP *can* let you access numbers 1 and 3 from a variable contains number `13` using the same syntax used to access array members, it doesn't make an array out of integer. It is merely a "syntax sugar".

You have to **verify** your impressions before starting to write a question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure?

```
$myNumber = 13;

$myArray = array("test" => "data");

if(is_array($myNumber)) {
    echo "myNumber is an array!";
}else{
    if(is_numeric($myNumber)) {
        echo "myNumber is not an array, but it is a number!";
    }
}
```

I get *myNumber is not an array, but it is a number!*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`gettype`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) function.

```
$type = gettype($variable);
if ( $type == 'array' ) {
  // it's an array
} else if ( $type == 'integer' ) {
  // it's an integer
} else {
  // it's a trap !
}
```

Comment: From the German gettype documentation (loosely translated): `Warning
Never use gettype to check for a certain type, because the returned string may be changed in the future. Furthermore this method is slow because it involves string comparison.

Use the is_*-functions instead.` http://php.net/manual/de/function.gettype.php